# Need assistence to do simple pipeline in F#

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I want to use this function *[let CopyDir target source filterFile ...(line 219)](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/FileHelper.fs)* and specify a filter. The idea is that the filter will contains files which will be excluded. Right now I am using a string value *log4net* and it is working but I want to replace it with *nugetDependencies* which is a collection of strings. Would you help me pls

`let nugetDependencies = getDependencies "./packages.config" 
let excludeNuget (path : string) = path.Contains "log4net" |> not
CopyDir nugetToolsDir (buildDir @@ package) excludeNuget`

UPDATE:
Fixed wrong URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to read the question a few times to understand it. My understand is that you want to filter a list of file paths by a list of exclusions--with "log4net" being an example of an exclusion.

I'd go something like this, taking advantage of [List.exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370309.aspx):

```ml
let excludePaths (pathsToExclude : string list) (path: string) =
    pathsToExclude |> List.exists (fun exPath -> path.Contains(exPath)) |> not
```

This implementation can actually curry the labda function `fun exPath -> path.Contains(exPath)` into simply `path.Contains` since the method takes a single argument, which would give us:

```ml
let excludePaths (pathsToExclude : string list) (path: string) =
    pathsToExclude |> List.exists path.Contains |> not
```

Currying (the F# formal term is [partial application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx)) can also be put to use here to *bind an argument* to the function. To create a check for "log4net", you can simply do this:

```ml
let nugetExclusions = ["log4net"]
let excludeNuget = excludePaths nugetExclusions
```

Just add all of the nuget paths you need to exclude from the list.

---

Since you are comparing paths `contains` doesn't have a case-insensitive overload. At least not out of the box. You can add an extension function to string, though. A C# implementation is [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/612512).

Here's a F# implementation of the extension method *(note that I made this with a small-case contains--F# functions and overloads don't mix)*:

```ml
type System.String with 
    member x.contains (comp:System.StringComparison) str = 
        x.IndexOf(str,comp) >= 0
```

With this [type extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx) in place we can change the `excludePaths` function to this (again, I'm currying the newly created `contains` extension method:

```ml
let excludePaths (pathsToExclude : string list) (path: string) =
    pathsToExclude 
        |> List.exists (path.contains StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        |> not
```

I hope you continue to use F#.

Comment: It took me 5 hours to flatten the nugetDependencies because it was a collection of tuples. Now everything works. thank you.

Comment: +1, but terminology quibble: "Curry" is commonly misunderstood; it is not the same as partial application.  Rather, currying is the process of converting a function that takes multiple arguments to a function that takes a single argument and returns another function (which in turn takes one argument, etc.).  In other words, currying is the concept that allows partial application.  I also note that passing path.Contains to List.exists is neither currying nor partial application; it's just passing a function as an argument to a function.

Comment: Gotcha, but partial application was used to make the function that was passed as an argument, right? (I didn't bind the partially bound `path.Contains StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to a name, though.)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
let excludeNuget (path : string) =
    nugetDependencies
    |> Seq.exists (fun x -> path.Contains x)
```

Comment: Aren't You missing a `|> not` at the end of pipeline?

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki I don't know... Shouldn't it return `true` to exclude something? (The OP is, I think, not entirely clear...)

Comment: Yep, there should be |> not. I am trying to debug this. This is my first time doing something with F#. I have some stupid type error "string*string but expected string".

Comment: Well, what type is nugetDependencies?

Comment: string * string list The first element of the tuple is what I actually need. I managed to flatten the collection to the correct type, 10x